# Will upgrading to Windows 8 wipe my raids?

Tags: windows, raid, upgrade

I'm currently running Windows 7 and i have setup a spanned partition and mirrored partition within windows 7 disk management.

If i upgrade to Windows 8 will i lose all the data on these drives?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't there is an upgrade path to windows 8 from Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

A typical Windows installation will not format partitions, unless you ask it to. Still, I hope you are not planning to install it on a partition where you have important files. There's always a chance that something can wrong...

Comment: no i have a SSD for the OS, then 2x 3TB on spanned and 2x 3TB in mirror. If i just do an upgrade on the SSD it won't touch the other drives will it?

Comment: Nope. Just go ahead and upgrade it.